# Disable or Change MediaWiki Domain Spam Filter

Tags: mediawiki

In our Wiki Installation (internal) we often post links. For the first time I have now this message:

```
The text you wanted to save was blocked by the spam filter.
This is probably caused by a link to a blacklisted external site.

The following text is what triggered our spam filter: uservoice.com
```

I mean uservoice.com should not be black listed?

How to change that? We are using the MediaWiki software installed on our own servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using the [global blacklist](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Spam_blacklist) via [Extension:SpamBlacklist](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:SpamBlacklist). Unfortunately it's maintained by people who mainly care about the English Wikipedia and don't mind much if other wikis are hurt by the rules. You can use your wiki's [MediaWiki:Spam-whitelist](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki:Spam-whitelist) page to override remote rules.

Comment: I tried the MediaWiki:Spam-whitelist, but I don't know what sytax to use there.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's just a matter of editing the [spam blacklist file](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki:Spam-blacklist).  See the [tutorial for that extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:SpamBlacklist).